# Google Analytics tracking code in the checkout issue

Tags: magento-1, onepage-checkout, google-analytics

I m trying to implement the steps from the tracking code for onepage checkout. I expected to have smth like this:

```
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
    'step': 1,  // or  'step': 'payment'
});
```

By doing this:

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = Checkout.prototype.gotoSection.wrap(function(parentMethod, section, reloadProgressBlock) {
       parentMethod(section, reloadProgressBlock);
       var _gaq = _gaq || [];
       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage'); ?>' + section + '/']);
});
```

I followed this [article](https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/03/tracking-magentos-onepage-checkout-steps-in-google-analytics/), but I don't get any results in the analytics.

Any idea what am i doing wrong? thx